# class constructor with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

### task

to make it possible to pass named paramteres to new bb-backed objects

### example

```
initialize : function(foo, bar, baz){
  this.foo = foo;
  ...
}


new Foo(value0, value1, value2)
```

### question

Is it possible without modifying the library source code?

Comment: What's wrong with the usual `options` object?

Comment: it's matter of taste, i don't like passing parameters inside another object

Comment: the 'initialize' you used here is of model or collection or view??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source you'll see that Model calls `initialize` like this:

```
Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
  // ...
  this.initialize(attributes, options);
};
```

But Collection, Router, and View call it like this:

```
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

And as we all know, [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) does this:

> Calls a function with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided as an array.

and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is:

> An array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

So for models you're stuck with the standard [documented interface](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) but for the rest you can do things like this:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(a, b, c, d) {
        // ...
    }
});
new View('where', 'is', 'pancakes', 'house?');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5ZD6z/

Note that doing this violates the documented [Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor), [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-constructor), and [View](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) interfaces so don't be surprised if using this undocumented behavior causes new and interesting bugs or breaks mysteriously after an upgrade. I'd recommend sticking to the documented interfaces and if it really bothers you so much, write constructor functions:

```
function make_thing(a, b c) {
    return new Thing({
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c
    });
}
```

and move on to more productive things.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JavaScript objects as parameters into the constructor, take a look at the [docu for Model.extend](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend):

```
MyModel = Backbobe.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        this.foo = options.foo;
    }
});

//pass your options as second parameter in the constructor call
// the first parameter is used as your model data    
var myModel = new MyModel({},{foo:bar});
```

Comment: Than you should mention this in your question. Its always better to told us what you've tried so far. Btw. whats the problem with the build in solution?